# How submit a button in asp.net.vb?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am currently learning to program in asp.net and I am writing to seek help on the following issue below:

I am trying to execute the following connection below but I when click the button connect in the browser, nothing happens.

**aspx.vb code:**

```
  Imports System.Data
  Imports System.Data.SqlClient
  Imports System.Configuration

Partial Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

' Public Sub Button1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim connectionString As String
    Dim connection As SqlConnection
    connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SQLDbConnection").ToString
    connection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Try
        connection.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Not working")
    End Try
    If connection.State = 1 Then
        MsgBox(" working")
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

asp.net code:

```
 <%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

  <!DOCTYPE html>

  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head id="Head1" runat="server">
  <title></title>
  </head>
 <body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"  />


 </div>
 </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

I tried adding "Onclick = "submit" to the asp.net code but it kept through an error.
Any help would be very much appreciated. 
Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways to wire up this button event. The first would be in code behind by modifying your signature to add the `Handles` keyword:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
```

The second would be in the html side by defining the onClick event to be assigned to the function itself

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onClick="Button1_Click" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response and help. I am really sorry to say, I already tried this approach and it always gives me "Handles clause requires a WithEvent variable" error in the behind code, and it also does not recognize "Button1_click" as member of 'ASP.default_2_aspx'.

Comment: @user15714185: What version of .Net are you using? If you're getting the "WithEvents" error, it means that your control has not been properly initialized. Check in the properties window for that control. You should see a button at the top with a little lightning bolt. If you click on that it will show you all of the events for that control. You can select the function there under the "click". However, if your control is declared in the code behind of your page, you will need to change its declaration to read: `Protected WithEvents Button1 as Button`

Comment: I really appreciate your time and help Joel. I got the web form to work in VS2010 using the same code above but could not get it to work in VS2012.  I am using VS express for this web application, hence I did not have the control icon in the properties window of that html control.  Thank so you much for your help and time.

Answer (score 2):

Just modify your VB.Net code like this using [**Handles**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6k46st1y%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
     ' Your code here
End Sub
```